# Assertion in verilog

Tags: verilog, simulation, assert

In my Verilog project, the signal "CsrPlugin_exceptionPortCtrl_exceptionContext_code" is typically set to 4'bxxxx under normal conditions and take values from 4'b0000 to 4'b1111 during exceptional conditions. To monitor this signal during simulation, I aim to identify exceptional conditions and promptly respond. I have implemented the following code:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (CsrPlugin_exceptionPortCtrl_exceptionContext_code >= 0) begin
    $display("crash");
    $stop;
  end
end
```

I want to ask if possible to realize this goal by using assert?

Comment: 'assert' is a **system** verilog construct. It does not exist in just *verilog*.

Comment: Yes, this could work in my design, and I would like to know if possible to realize with assert@toolic

Comment: Is it possible to just change ".v" to ".sv" and use assert? @Serge

Comment: @KabiLink, Usually yes, depends on the tool you are using.

Comment: I want to ask why I get a negative score @dave_59

Comment: @KabiLink, wasn’t me.

Comment: Thank you, because I have received negative point many times without any suggestion, that makes me confused @dave_59

Comment: @KabiLink, I think people are confused by your use of the word _assert_, which is a SystemVerilog verification construct (and keyword). You have only used the [tag:Verilog] tag. And what do you mean by _respond_?

Comment: Ok, I understand. Because I use VHDL before, they have "assert" keyword, so I suppose it's possible to use in Verilog. Respond means these 2 instruction after "begin" '$display("crash");
    $stop;', which means reaction when detect except condition @dave_59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In verilog you could emulate an assert with a define.

```
`define my_assert(signal, value) \
if (signal >= value) $display("my error message"); \
$stop;


always @(posedge clk) begin
  `my_assert(CsrPlugin_exceptionPortCtrl_exceptionContext_code, 0);
```

Comment: I want to ask why I get a negative score

Comment: I went ahead and gave you an upvote because it seems like a reasonable question. I had the same question coming from VHDL. I know my suggestion is a bit of a kludge but if you can't use or aren't familiar with SV (my case) this will work.

Comment: Thank you, because I have received negative point many times without any suggestion, that makes me confused @Ray H